# CodeIgniter unable to get column names in insert function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, insert

I have the following in my controller:

```
$client_data = array(
    $client_id = null,
    $client_name = $this->input->post('client_name'),
    $client_contact = $this->input->post('client_contact'),
    $client_phone = $this->input->post('client_phone')
);
```

which I am passing onto my model's function like so:

```
public function add_client($client_data) {
    $this->db->insert('clients', $client_data);
}
```

As far as I can tell, I have done all correctly, however CodeIgniter is unable to read my table's column names as it throws this error:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0, 1, 2, 3) VALUES (NULL, 'Test Client', '' at line 1

INSERT INTO `clients` (0, 1, 2, 3) VALUES (NULL, 'Test Client', 'Test Person', '123486')

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/foobar/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

I already have my database and db helper loaded. My table structure is as follows: `client_id, client_name, client_person, client_phone`. What am I missing?

Comment: print `$client_data`.what is the output?

Comment: Does your query NSERT INTO `clients` (0, 1, 2, 3) ..... is working in PhpMyAdmin ?

Comment: @Saty added my column names. Query will not work because that is not the correct column names.

Comment: In array declaration change `$client_id = null,` to `'client_id' => null,` ets

Comment: `'client_id' =>null` you should pass associate array'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replace your array to this:

```
$client_data = array(
    'client_id' => null,
    'client_name' => $this->input->post('client_name'),
    'client_contact' => $this->input->post('client_contact'),
    'client_phone' => $this->input->post('client_phone')
);
```

Comment: Yep! This was it. Just a syntax mistake, thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @AliIshaq you're welcome ) don't forget to mark the question as solved ))